# Python argparse mutually exclusive with stdin being one of the options

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, stdin, argparse

I would like my script to receive these mutually exclusive **input** options:

- an input file containing a JSON (`script.py -i input.json`);
- a string containing a JSON (`script.py '{"a":1}'`);
- a JSON from stdin (`echo '{"a":1}' | script.py` or `cat input.json | script.py`).

and these mutually exclusive output **options**:

- an output file containing a JSON;
- a JSON in stdout.

So I tried with this code

```
import json,sys,argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Template for python script managing JSON as input/output format')

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--input-file', '-i',  type=str, help='Input file name containing a valid JSON.', default=sys.stdin)
group.add_argument('json',    nargs='?',  type=str, help='Input string containing a valid JSON.' , default=sys.stdin)
parser.add_argument('--output-file', '-o',type=str, help='Output file name.')

args = parser.parse_args()

if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    data = sys.stdin.read()
else:
#    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.input_file :
        data=open(args.input_file).read()
    elif args.json :
        data=args.json


datain=json.loads(data)

dataout=json.dumps(datain, indent=2)

if args.output_file :
        output_file=open(args.output_file, 'w')
        output_file.write(dataout+'\n')
        output_file.close()
else:
    print (dataout)
```

But it does not work with stdin as it requires at least one of the two `group` options.

How can I add stdin in the list of input options?

Adding the `default=sys.stdin` argument works if I call it like that

```
echo '{}' | ./script.py -
```

but not like that:

```
echo '{}' | ./script.py
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would take advantage of `argparse.FileType` with a default value of `sys.stdin`.

```
import json,sys,argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Template for python script managing JSON as input/output format')

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument(
    '--input-file', '-i',
    type=argparse.FileType('r'),
    default=sys.stdin,
    help='Input file name containing a valid JSON.')
group.add_argument(
    'json',
    nargs='?',
    type=str,
    help='Input string containing a valid JSON.')
parser.add_argument(
    '--output-file', '-o',
    type=argparse.FileType('w'),
    help='Output file name.',
    default=sys.stdout)

args = parser.parse_args()
data = args.json or args.input_file.read()

datain=json.loads(data)
dataout=json.dumps(datain, indent=2)
args.output_file.write(dataout)
```

Comment: Great! But with this code, empty stdin and no arguments (`.\script.py`) result in waiting indefinitely, while it should (in my opinion) show that at least one method (stdin, string or file) is required

Comment: Then how would one type input into your program? "Reading from stdin" means reading from the console when input is not redirected.

Comment: Sorry for using wrong terminology :) I mean that the input comes from piping, such as `echo '{}' | script.py` or `cat input.json | script.py`.

Comment: Right. That's one way to use stdin. But an equally valid way is to type while your program is running. If you intentionally exclude the ability to enter text into your program by typing at the console, that will confuse your users.

Comment: Uhm... ok, but I don't understand: now, if I type something like `{}` while the script is waiting, and then I press return, I don't obtain any response. The typing ability is not a key point to me.

Comment: Right, it is waiting for the next line of text. After all, your data might be longer than one line long. When you have finished entering your data, indicate end-of-file by pressing the end-of-file key sequence that your OS uses. If you are on UNIX or Linux, that is probably Control-D. If you are on Windows, it is probably Control-Z.

Comment: `Ctrl-D`It works!  Can I separate these two features (piping and direct input)? For example with a flag `-d` also waits for direct input, otherwise not?

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
group.add_argument('--input-file', '-i')
```

You could test

```
if args.input_file is None:
   <-i wasn't supplied>
else:
    if args.input_file == '-':
        f = sys.stdin
    else:
        f = open(args.input_file)
    data = f.read()  # etc
```

Or may be better:

```
    if args.input_file == '-':
        data = sys.stdin.read()
    else
        with open(args.input_file) as f:
            f.read()
```

A tricky thing with `stdin` is that you don't want to close it after use like you would with a regular file name.  And you can't use it in a `with`.

Similarly with `stdout`.

Some code sets a flag when it opens a file, as opposed to receiving an already open one, so it can remember to close the file at the end.

```
group.add_argument('--input-file','-i',nargs='?', default=None, const=sys.stdin)
```

would set `arg.input_file` to `stdin` when given `-i` without an argument.  But I think looking for a plain `-` string is a better idea.