# Python "template" module for both command line scripts and imported module

Tags: python, json, module, argparse

I would like to write a python "template" module in order to give all my scripts the same behavior.

The behavior is the following:

- if the script runs in **command line**, it accepts arguments treated with argparse. These arguments are basically:

  - take in input a `json` from stdin, from file, or from a string argument;
  - give in output a `json` in stdout or in a file.
- if the script is **imported as a module**, it has classes/functions managing the following situations:

  - take in input an object from who called it;
  - give in output an object so that who called it can use it.

### What I have done:

### The "template" part template.py

It behaves from command line exactly as I want thanks to these suggestions:
[Python argparse mutually exclusive with stdin being one of the options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200536/python-argparse-mutually-exclusive-with-stdin-being-one-of-the-options)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json,sys,argparse,os

def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Template for python script managing JSON as input/output format. \
                                                  A JSON file can be [], {}, "string", 123, true, false, null.')

    infile=['-i','--input-file']
    kwinfile={'type':argparse.FileType('r'), 'help':'Input file name containing a valid JSON. Default and priority: standard input.'}

    jstring=['-j','--json']
    kwjstring={'type':str,  'nargs':'?', 'help':'Input file name containing a valid JSON. Default and priority: standard input.'}

    outfile=['-o','--output-file']
    kwoutfile={'type':argparse.FileType('w'), 'help':'Output file name. Default: standard output.', 'default':sys.stdout}

    pretty=['-p','--pretty']
    kwpretty={'action':'store_true', 'help':'If set, JSON output  will be formatted in pretty print.'}

    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

    group.add_argument(*infile, **kwinfile)
    group.add_argument(*jstring, **kwjstring)
    parser.add_argument(*outfile, **kwoutfile)
    parser.add_argument(*pretty, **kwpretty)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return(args)

def input(*data):
    args=main()

    # if data :
    #     datain=data[0]

    # else :
    if not sys.stdin.isatty(): # pipe
        data=sys.stdin.read()
    else:  # no pipe
        if not len(sys.argv) > 1 or (args.input_file == None and args.json == None) : # no arguments or no input
            data='null'
        else :
            data = args.json or args.input_file.read()

    try:
        datain = json.loads(data)
    except:
        output({'script_name':(sys.argv[0]),
                'error': 'Input is not a valid JSON.',
                'data': data})
        sys.exit(0)

    return(datain)


def output(*datain) :
    args=main()
    if datain :
        datain=datain[0]

    indent = 2 if args.pretty else None

    dataout = json.dumps(datain, indent=indent, ensure_ascii=False)
    args.output_file.write(dataout+os.linesep)

    return(dataout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I hope this is the best way to realize it.

### The example "calculate_area"

Now, if I import it in a script using

```
import template as t

def main():

    inp=t.input() # {"x":8, "y":2}

    out={'area' : inp['x'] * inp['y'] }

    return(t.output(out))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the script act in command line as I want:

```
$ echo '{"x":8, "y":2}' | ./calculate_area.py -p
{
  "area": 16
}
```

### The "calculate_sqrt" script to test it as a module

Now I want a third script to import it as a module.

```
import template as t
import calculate_area as i
import numpy as np
import json

def main():

    inp=json.loads(i.main())

    out={'sqrt of area' : np.sqrt(inp['area']) }

    return(t.output(out))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here the problems start:

```
$ echo '{"x":8, "y":2}' | ./calculate_sqrt.py -p
{
  "area": 16
}
{
  "sqrt of area": 4.0
}
```

- Why do I obtain the two input instead of only the last one?

Moreover:

- How to avoid to input it in `json`? Saying instead: "if the module is called via `import`, then the input/output will be via objects, else it will be via `json` in command line"?

I saved my code here:
https://github.com/orsa-unige/python-templates/tree/simplified-example

Comment: In your `Template` code, you call `main()`, but don't do anything with the returned `args`.  In `input` and `output` you call it again, this time saving `args`.  But I don't see any calls to either of those functions.

Comment: `FileType` is setup to accept `-` to mean `stdin` or `stdout`.  That should let you accept redirected (maybe even piped?) input/output without special tests.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't understand... I call it so that I can use `args` values

Comment: `i.main()` produces the `area` string.  It returns it, but also writes to a file.

Comment: How can avoid it? commenting out `args.output_file.write` results in no output; replacing `return` with `print` produces the same behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the outline of a good,in my opinion, base script:

```
import json,sys,argparse,os

def parser(argv=None):
    # if argv is None, uses the sys.argv[1:]
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(....)
    ...
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return(args)

def input(args, *data):

    # if data :
    #     datain=data[0]

    if args.input_file is not None: 
        # input_file might be sys.stdin (if '-')   
        data = args.input_file.read()
    # stdin should work for < redirection
    # I don't know if works for pipe
    ...
    return(datain)

def output(args, *datain) :
    if datain :
        datain=datain[0]
    # output_file might be stdout
    ....
    return(dataout)

def main(args):
    datain = input(args, [])
    dataout = output(args, datain)
    return dataout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parser()
    main(args)
```

This runs the parser only once if called as a script.  If imported it is up to the importer script to run this parser.

A `parser` may be run multiple times, but usually isn't needed - at least not if the `Namespace` can be passed around.  But each call the parser opens the input/output files.  Since one file is opened in write mode, the could result in overlapping opens.

The parser might be test with:

```
args = parser(['-i', 'inputfile.py', ....]
```

Another script could do

```
from template import parser, input, output
def main(args):
    ... input
    # do its own thing
    ... output
# etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. It allows to run parser only once. But now, when `import template as t`, I have to call `t.input(args,...)` and `t.output(args,...)` while it is not necessary, as the argument options should be the same for all scripts using the template.

Comment: Imported modules in Python provide functions and classes that the importer can use.  Your template model is an awkward fit.  What if a script want's additional controls?  Anyways, if calling the parser several times, I'd suggest getting rid of the `FileType`s.  Open and/or create the files yourself, only as needed, preferable in a `with` context.  The `input` function should not create the `output` file.  The `output` function should not open the `input` file that it does not use.  The parser shouldn't choke if you provide values that it doesn't recognize.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggestions. I'll update the code